# How to show that the interior of the causal future is contained in the chronological future?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, topology

I want to show that $int[J^+(S)\subset I^+(S)$ for an arbitrary set *S*.  I've done most of it I think but not up to the level of rigor that I would like.  Here's what I have:

Let $p \in int[J^+(S)]$.  Assume that $p \notin I^+(S)$.  (Proof by contradition.)  By the Corollary to Theorem 8.1.2 in Wald it follows that any causal curve from *S* to *p* will be a null geodesic.  Since $J^+(S) \subset \overline {I^+(S)}$ (Wald problem 8.2.a), it follows that $p \in \overline {I^+(S)}$.  Thus $p\in\overline {I^+(S)}-\overline I^+(S)$.  But $\overline {I^+(S)} = \overline {J^+(S)}$. (Wald, bottom p. 191)  Thus $p\in\overline {J^+(S)}-\overline I^+(S)$.  Since $p \in int[J^+(S)$, there exists a neighborhood *U* of *p* such that $U \subset J^+(S)$.  Let $q \in (M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$.  Since $q \notin \overline {J^+(S)}$, it follows that $q \notin I^+(S)$.  But since $q\in U$, we have $q \in  J^+(S)$.  By the Corollary to Theorem 8.1.2, it follows that any causal curve from *S* to *q* is a null geodesic.  Since $(M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$ is open, it contains a neighborhood *W* of *q*.  Let $\lambda$ be a null geodesic from *S* to *q*.  We can make a small modification of $\lambda$ to get a timelike curve $\lambda'$ from *S* to $r \in W$.  But this implies $r \in I^+(S)$ which is impossible because $r \in W \subset (M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$ implies  $r\notin I^+(S)$.  So we have our proof.

Except, I don't know how to show that such a q exists!  How do we know that $(M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$ is not empty?  What if *S* just consisted of a single point and *M* were just the future light cone?  In that case, $(M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$ would be empty because $J^+(S)$ would be all of $M$.  The problem with that is that in that case $M$ would not be a manifold.  It would be a manifold with boundary.  But still the question remains of how to show that $(M-\overline {J^+(S)})\cap U$ is not empty in general.  I thought it would be simple topology.  If you stick to simple examples, it is fairly obvious.  But I can't quite come up with the required steps and I am not even sure what I would need to do it.  Evidently theorems about manifolds vs. manifolds with boundaries requires cohomology and so that can't be what is required.  Perhaps using a coordinate system with one axis in the $\lambda$ direction and then some handwaving about their being no points on one side of that line?  That doesn't quite seem adequate because the topologies under consideration can get quite unintuitive with remove points, etc.  Maybe that is not insurmountable, but then my question is just is that indeed what is expected/needed?  This is part of problem 8.2.b in Wald and so everything that is needed to prove this should be available to one at that point in the text.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a proper answer since I do not have time to enter into the details of  your attempt. However the proof immediately arises from a fundamental general result, due to Penrose (*), for causal relations in time oriented spacetimes (see O’Neill’s textbook for instance, but it should appear also in Wald’s textbook as it is of utmost relevance):

*If $p$ stays in the causal (chronological) future of $q$ and $r$ stays in the chronological (resp. causal) future of $p$, then $r$ stays in the chronological future of $q$.*

Now consider $r\in Int[J^+(S)]$. Therefore, there is an open neighbourhood of $r$ whose points can be connected to points in $S$ by future directed causal curves exiting $S$. Take $p$ in that neighbourhood in the chronological past of $r$. There is a future-directed causal curve from $q\in S$ to $r$, and a timelike analogous curve from $p$ to $r$. On account of the quoted general result, $r$ belongs to the chronological future of $q$, i.e., of $S$. That is the thesis.

---

(*) [2.18 Proposition in R. Penrose: Techniques of Differential Topology in Relativity (CBMS-NSF Regional Conference Series in Applied Mathematics, Series Number 7)](https://www.kfki.hu/%7Eiracz/sgimp/cikkek/cenzor/Penrose_todtir.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  My problem is internal to Wald's order of presentation.  I did not know about those Penrose lectures.  Wald's timelike paths are not piecewise while Penrose's are.  But I looked at Penrose around 2.18 and the key take away for me was that he uses compactness of the path to get 2.18 and again a bit later.  Wald uses it only once so I think Wald wants the student to use the compactness of the path again to answer my question.  I'm going to delve into it this week and get back to you.  Thanks!  Great help!

Comment: Hello Valter, I gave it a bit more thought today.  If we approach it your way, then my question becomes: How do you know such a p exists?  If I know that, then I can do a Waldesque proof in just a few lines.  It's only 99% obvious to me and I worry about the 1% because this is a prelude to the singularity theorems and so I worry about remove points and weird situations.  Causal curves can be degenerate so the existence of a causal curve from S to p doesn't directly address the worry.  Imagine S=r and it is a Big Bang singularity for example.

Comment: Let us call $U$ an open neighborhood of $r$ included in the causal  future of $q$. Take a timelike past directed vector $u$ at $r$ and consider the geodesic $\gamma :[0, c) \ni t \mapsto \gamma(t)\in M$ with tangent vector $u$  exiting $r$ for  $t=0$. For continuity reasons, the geodesics stays in the neighborhood $U$ for some $t_0>0$. $p:=\gamma(t_0)\neq r$ is in the chronological past of $r$ and also stays in $U$ as wanted.

Comment: Notice that it is not possible that $\gamma(t)= r$ for all $t$ because its initial tangent vector would be $0$ which is not timelike.

Comment: I will meet Bob Wald next summer, I could ask him what was his intention about that exercise :)

Comment: However, even if S =r, *we are also assuming that r is in the interior of the causal future of S*. So, by the very *definition of interior*, there must be that open neighbourhood of r and the proof goes on as I said…I cannot imagine a that pathological situation, maybe it is not possible, but it does not matter: *with the said hypotheses the proof goes right*. Obviously, when assuming Penrose’s statement.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  Many textbooks have this as an exercise--I just saw it in O'Neill.  But it is the first one that has forced me to contemplate the boundary of the manifold.  On [0, 1], [0,.2) is an open set.  If we just took our manifold to be $J^+(p)$ as a subset of Minkowski space, then we could choose a point r along a null geodesic from p and there would be an open neighborhood of r for which $I^-(p)$ is the empty set.  But, that cannot happen because our M's cannot have boundaries.  But, then the very very Waldesque question is: where are we using that fact in our proofs?

Comment: And then the deeper question is just: why aren't we considering manifolds with boundaries when we are exploring the causal structure of spacetime?  Mathematicians are free to limit themselves however they please.  But physicists presumably need a physical reason!  But what is that physical reason?  OK, coffee is poured.  I'm off to O'Neill, Penrose, Hawking, et. al.  I'll keep you updated.  Thanks again!

Comment: Typo:"for which $I^-(r)$ is the empty set."

Comment: OK, I'm relieved! Manifolds with boundaries return with a vengence in Hawking and Ellis' Sect. 9.2 "Gravitational Collapse; Black Holes" (p. 310) and earlier (p. 284).  I'm not yet sure whether Wald prescinds, finesses or punts when boundaries threaten in his presentation, but I can sleep better now knowing that boundary matters get addressed by Hawking.  Wald motivates using manifolds without boundaries by arguing that locally spacetime is like $\mathbb{R}^4$.  But remove points are less intuitive than boundaries IMHO so boundaries need to be addressed!

Comment: No issues with manifold with boudary enter this problem. $J^+(q)$ is a manifod with boudary in a strict sense only close to $q$ and removing $q$ from it. But here these notions are not pertinent.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you would have to remove q from it.  But if we allowed such a manifold, then our open sets would be defined differently and so $Int[J^+(S)]$ could include points on the boundary (points on null geodesics) but those points would not be in $[I^+(S)]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142679/discussion-between-mster8390-and-valter-moretti).

Comment: Sorry, it is my policy not to discuss in chat as my spare time is very limited...